# How do start a background sudo task on startup (like a daemon)?

Tags: debian, sudo, startup, background-process

I am familiar with controlling preconfigured system daemons (as packaged by Debian) with the `systemctl` command. I also have a custom "service" that I start manually with:

```
sudo process --option
```

Because it runs with `sudo` I can't add it to the "Startup" list (that start when I log into my desktop session). In any event, I would prefer to run it:

- on system startup
- in the background
- as root

Ideally I would also like the option to:

- stop/start it from the command line (with or similarly to `systemctl`)

In other words, treat it like any other system daemon. How can I configure my custom service to act like a regular, preconfigured one?

Comment: Well, this is the **very basic** usage of systemd.

Comment: @TomaszPala I've rephrased the question to make it more obvious that I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 2):

Any recent tutorial about systemd will give you the basics about running services with systemd.

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/foo.service 
[Unit]
Description=myservice

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/myservice/executable

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then activate it:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable myservice
# Start / Stop
systemctl start myservice
systemctl stop myservice
```